# Text to image convertion using php getting blur image

Tags: php, image, png, transparent

I have used https://github.com/ttodua/useful-php-scripts/blob/master/text-to-image.php for text to image convertion.

Actually i have to create an image from text and show it on different background colors. for that created a transparent image and showing on red background colour. but showing white color patches around the text while creating the transparent image. How can i create smooth text image on any background color?

Could you please help me on this. below is my code.

My Html

```
<div class="box--h logo_bg_color1_preview fl-d fl-ac" style="background-color:red;">
<div class="box--l fl-d fl-ac">
<img src="logo.png?q=0.73948100 1606166692">
</div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

My Converted Image transparent background

[image]

```
public function hexToRgb($hex, $alpha = false) {
   $hex      = str_replace('#', '', $hex);
   $length   = strlen($hex);
   $rgb['r'] = hexdec($length == 6 ? substr($hex, 0, 2) : ($length == 3 ? str_repeat(substr($hex, 0, 1), 2) : 0));
   $rgb['g'] = hexdec($length == 6 ? substr($hex, 2, 2) : ($length == 3 ? str_repeat(substr($hex, 1, 1), 2) : 0));
   $rgb['b'] = hexdec($length == 6 ? substr($hex, 4, 2) : ($length == 3 ? str_repeat(substr($hex, 2, 1), 2) : 0));
   if ( $alpha ) {
      $rgb['a'] = $alpha;
   }
   return $rgb;
    }


function TextToImage($text="hello world",$textColor)
{
$newline_after_letters=40; 
$font='./myfont.ttf'; 
$size=24;
$rotate=0;
$padding=2;
$transparent=true;
$bg_color=array('red'=>255,'grn'=>255,'blu'=>255);
$textRgbColor = $this->hexToRgb($textColor);
$color=array('red'=>$textRgbColor['r'],'grn'=>$textRgbColor['g'],'blu'=>$textRgbColor['b']);
        //other version: pastebin(dot).com/XVVUyWGD
        $amount_of_lines= ceil(strlen($text)/$newline_after_letters)+substr_count($text, '\n')+1;
        $all_lines=explode("\n", $text); $text=""; $amount_of_lines = count($all_lines);
        foreach($all_lines as $key=>$value){ 
            while( mb_strlen($value,'utf-8')>$newline_after_letters){   
                $text_final .= mb_substr($value, 0, $newline_after_letters, 'utf-8')."\n";
                $value = mb_substr($value, $newline_after_letters, null, 'utf-8');
            }  
            $text .= mb_substr($value, 0, $newline_after_letters, 'utf-8') . ( $amount_of_lines-1 == $key ? "" : "\n");
        }
        
        //
        Header("Content-type: image/png");
        $width=$height=$offset_x=$offset_y = 0;
        if(!is_file($font)) { file_put_contents($font,file_get_contents('https://github.com/potyt/fonts/raw/master/macfonts/Arial%20Unicode%20MS/Arial%20Unicode.ttf')); }
    
        // get the font height.
        $bounds = ImageTTFBBox($size, $rotate, $font, "W");
        if ($rotate < 0)        {$font_height = abs($bounds[7]-$bounds[1]); } 
        elseif ($rotate > 0)    {$font_height = abs($bounds[1]-$bounds[7]); } 
        else { $font_height = abs($bounds[7]-$bounds[1]);}
        // determine bounding box.
        $bounds = ImageTTFBBox($size, $rotate, $font, $text);
        if ($rotate < 0){       
        $width = abs($bounds[4]-$bounds[0]);
        $height = abs($bounds[3]-$bounds[7]);
        $offset_y = $font_height;                               
        $offset_x = 0;
        } 
        elseif ($rotate > 0) {  
        $width = abs($bounds[2]-$bounds[6]);
        $height = abs($bounds[1]-$bounds[5]);
        $offset_y = abs($bounds[7]-$bounds[5])+$font_height;
        $offset_x = abs($bounds[0]-$bounds[6]);
        } 
        else{                   
        $width = abs($bounds[4]-$bounds[6]);
        $height = abs($bounds[7]-$bounds[1]);
        $offset_y = $font_height; 
        $offset_x = 0;
        }
    
        $image = imagecreate($width+($padding*2)+1,$height+($padding*2)+1);
    
        $background = ImageColorAllocate($image, $bg_color['red'], $bg_color['grn'], $bg_color['blu']);
        $foreground = ImageColorAllocate($image, $color['red'], $color['grn'], $color['blu']);
    
        if ($transparent) ImageColorTransparent($image, $background);
        ImageInterlace($image, true);
      // render the image
        ImageTTFText($image, $size, $rotate, $offset_x+$padding, $offset_y+$padding, $foreground, $font, $text);
        imagealphablending($image, true);
        imagesavealpha($image, true);
      // output PNG object.
        $finalImage="abc.png";
        imagePNG($image, $finalImage, 0, NULL);
    imagedestroy($image);
    }
```

Comment: any one plz sugguest